# node connect-flash display message while passing data

Tags: node.js

I just started experimenting with connect-flash and have a weird effect, if I do this, my code works:

```
router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  req.flash('test', 'message goes here');  
  res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('test') });
});
```

but if I do this, it doesn't (it shows a number in my template that increases every time i load:

```
router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('test', 'message goes here') });
});
```

Anyone know what's going on / how I can set the message on one line instead of two?.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you have already assigned the key "test" a value, thus when rendering **message** on your template it will retrieve "*message goes here*"

For the second part you will have to loop, assuming you are using jade template:

```
for message in flash
     p= message.message
```